Why should we directly include the header declaring a symbol?
I'm using clang-tidy v20.0 for static analysis and I'm in trouble with the misc-include-cleaner check. In every source file, I get a warning due to indirect inclusion of headers.
For instance, when using struct timeval I include <sys/time.h> but it's actually defined in <bits/types/struct_timeval.h> which is included by <sys/time.h>. clang-tidy shows two warnings in this case.

included header time.h is not used directly [misc-include-cleaner]


no header providing "timeval" is directly included [misc-include-cleaner]

I know that disabling this check is possible, but I'm not sure if I this is the proper solution.
Checks:
  - "*"
  - "-misc-include-cleaner"

In other cases, I've tried suppressing the warnings for certain headers, but the problems get bigger.
# Allow in-directly including some headers as they are included by other headers
# For instance, <string.h> is deprecated in C++ and can be replaced with <cstring>
# However, including <cstring> doesn't satisfy this check
- key: misc-include-cleaner.IgnoreHeaders
  value: string.h;struct_timeval.h

So, should I disable this check so as not to get mad or fix all warnings related to it? I'm not sure how beneficial it is.

It should not raise such warnings. Please post the complete .clang-tidy and how you invoke clang-tidy.

@3CxEZiVlQ I don't have any other configuration related to this in .clang-tidy file right now. I'm invoking it with clang-tidy --config-file .clang-tidy -p build <file path> or by initiating a full build via CMake where I configure the project with static analysis enabled.

iwyu has trick to handle those cases, with mappings or pragma. possibly not up to date...

You should be including <sys/time.h> according to manpage. I guess the only course of action is disabling the check for now and raising an issue to clang-tidy (preferably also submitting a PR that resolves it).

And to address the title question: It's a good idea to include what you use and not depend on transitive includes. For example, gcc 12 and earlier had #include <string> in iostream and people considered it granted. gcc 13 suddenly cleaned up its includes and iostream no longer contains string, leading to errors. Including what you use also helps within your project, because you can modify headers without worrying that some source on the other end of the project will suddenly fail to compile. But this exact case is a false positive - the tool is wrong to report these.
